# what does #+ mean in bash scripting?

Tags: bash

I was reading a tutorial about bash scripting on https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html
and noticed that some comments begin with #+ instead of #

```
echo ls -l | sh
#  Passes the output of "echo ls -l" to the shell,
#+ with the same result as a simple "ls -l"
```

I'm guessing the author decided to use #+ to mention continued comment from the previous line.
Is this the case and is it a common convention in bash?

Comment: It's just their own (silly) convention (for comment continuation). By the way, the ABS used to be frown upon by Bash guys, as it used to be full of antipatterns. I don't know how the recent revisions are, but I believe there are much better sources out there.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf could you please recommend a better source or two then?

Comment: Have a look at the resources in the [Bash tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info). I guess that Lhunath's Bash guide must be good... at least it will focus on writing proper scripts (you know, quoting expansions, not using external tools in silly ways, etc.). The [BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) is also awesome (yet, not really a tutorial, but definitely worth reading!).

Comment: Thanks! @gniourf_gniourf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comments start with `#`. There is no convention associated with comments (well, they should be readable and about the code..........). The standard does not mention what syntax should a comment have. The string after `#` is not parsed, so `#+` is equivalent to `#!!@#$%^&*()` and is not anything special when parsed by Bash. The `#+` is just the author's convention to continue a comment in the next line if they didn't end the sentence in the previous line.

Answer (score -2):

This is not a convention but here, I assume like you, the author wanted to *link* both comments.

The real way to do it in bash is to use the multiline comment:

```
    : '
    This is a
    multiline comment.
    '
```

Please note that the space between the `:` and `'` is important.

Comment: Wrong, this is a multiline comment. Much easier to use than multi `#` :)

Comment: Comments with `#` are ignored by bash, but this, bash is gonna try to run this.

Comment: For those having problem with this, here is a cheat sheet: https://devhints.io/bash with `: '` as multiline. I've always used it without issues.

Comment: It _can_ be used for somewhat _hack_ as a multiline comment, as bash does not support multiline commenting, but it __IS__ a command equivalent to `true`. When you write `: something` the shell executes `fork() -> exec(true ....) -> waitpid() -> etc.. `. When you write `# something` the shell ignores it. These are not equivalent.

Comment: The `:` is a shell special utility as specified by POSIX, with it's (original ;) ) purpose to write empty `if` or `while` statements, ie. `if smth; then :; else :; fi`. POSIX documentation available [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/colon.html).

Comment: @KamilCuk: Since both `true` and `:` are builtin commands, the shell is unlikely to execute `fork()`. But I wouldn't write a multi-line comment that way. Any decent editor will let you insert a `#` at the beginning of each line in a range without having to type it N times.